# Is the a Django serializer to serialize reverse relations individually?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have these two models, where `A` has a many-to-one relation with `B`:

```
class A(models.Model):
  field_A1 = models.ForeignKey('B', ...)
  field_A2 = ...

class B(models.Model):
  field_B = ... #primary key
```

I know I can setup a serializer for `B` to also serialize the related instances of `A`, taking advantage of `.a_set`. For instance, if I tried to serialize an instance of `B` having two related instance of `A` I would get something like the following:

```
{
  "field_B": "instance of B",
  "a_set": [
    {
      "field_A2": "first related instance of A"
    },
    {
      "field_A2": "second related instance of A"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want the serialize to output instead is the 'product' of instance of `B` with the related instances of `A`, e.g. in the same scenario as in the previous example, I would like to get the following:

```
[
  {
    "field_B": "instance of B",
    "field_A": "FIRST related instance of A"
  },
  {
    "field_B": "instance of B",
    "field_A": "SECOND related instance of A"
  }
]
```

How can I obtain this in Django? Do I need to populate a data structure with the product myself or there's something built-in in the framework I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    field_B = serializers.IntegerField(source='field_A1.field_B')
    field_A = serializers.CharField(source='field_A2')

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('field_B', 'field_A')
```

Serializer fields can be anything based on your model field.

Read this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source